# как написать функцию которая выводит словесное описание числа на русском языке?

Tags: python

напишите функцию , которая принимает в качестве аргумента натуральное число  и возвращает его словесное описание на русском языке.

подскажите пожалуйста наиболее оптимальный вариант

```
    print(number_to_words(7))
    print(number_to_words(85))
```

должен выводить:

семь

восемьдесят пять

Comment: очевидно, что это тестовая задача и использовать сторонние библиотеки не надо. можете посмотреть чужие [исходники](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words/blob/master/num2words/lang_RU.py) (чтоб оценить объем требуемого кода). попробуйте для начала поддержать числа от 0 до 10, потом до 20 и т.д. как раз за день управитесь и в питоне прокачаетесь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [С клавиатуры вводится любое количество гривен. Вывести результат в числовом и текстовом виде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105572/%d0%a1-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 3):

Для этого вы можете использовать библиотеку [num2words](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words)

`pip install num2words`

Вот самый банальный пример, языки можно менять.

```
from num2words import num2words

def num_to_word(num):
    try:
        print(num2words(num, lang='ru'))
    except NotImplementedError:
        print(num2words(num, lang='en'))


num_to_word(23)
```